# Error: could not find native static library `ssl`, perhaps an -L flag is missing? on WIndows

Tags: windows, gcc, rust, openssl

I'm trying to build this project on windows. -> https://github.com/alexanderbanks/rust-api

https://users.rust-lang.org/t/error-could-not-find-native-static-library-ssl-perhaps-an-l-flag-is-missing-on-windows/46777
When I run cargo build I get following error. Please note I have updated the dependencies to

```
[dependencies]
iron = "0.6.1"
router = "0.6.0"
time = "0.2.16"
serde = "1.0.114"
serde_derive = "1.0.114"
serde_json = "1.0.57"
diesel = { version = "1.4.5", features = ["postgres"] }
diesel_codegen = { version = "0.16.1", features = ["postgres"] }
dotenv = "0.15.0"
bcrypt = "0.8.1"
rand = "0.7.3"
bodyparser = "0.8.0"
frank_jwt = "3.1.2"
```

Windows PATH
[image]

**ERROR**:

```
error: could not find native static library `ssl`, perhaps an -L flag is missing?

error: aborting due to previous error

error: could not compile `openssl-sys`.
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it to run by following the steps I found [here](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-openssl/issues/1086).

Create a directory somewhere (they used `C:\Tools`), then `cd` into it and run the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
cd vcpkg
.\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
.\vcpkg.exe install openssl:x64-windows-static
```

This took about 15 minutes to run on my computer.

Once it's done, you need to set the following environment variables:

```
SET OPENSSL_DIR=C:\Tools\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows-static
SET OPENSSL_STATIC=Yes
```

Once all that's done, `cd` back into your project directory and run cargo build; it should work now.