# Error installing OpenSSL using VCPKG on Visual Studio code: Error: in triplet x64-windows: Unable to find a valid Visual Studio instance

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, cmake, openssl, vcpkg

I am trying to fix the error I'm facing while running a rust program on my VScode as shown in the link below, install openssl and  and set the paths using vcpkg by following the post:
[Error: could not find native static library `ssl`, perhaps an -L flag is missing? on WIndows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63223387/error-could-not-find-native-static-library-ssl-perhaps-an-l-flag-is-missing)

According to the answer, I ran the following instructions through visual studio code terminal:

```
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
cd vcpkg
.\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
```

The above codes executed successfully but the code below to install openssl resulted in an error.

```
.\vcpkg.exe install openssl:x64-windows-static
```

error:

```
Error: in triplet x64-windows: Unable to find a valid Visual Studio instance
Could not locate a complete Visual Studio instance
```

How do I resolve the above error? I have cmake installed and functioning properly but still no luck trying to get vcpkg to install openssl.The paths mentioned in the link answer is also set and I am running all the codes above in the correct directory I made.

Directory where I ran the codes:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\wintun-maindtls\vcpkgfile\vcpkg>
```

Comment: As you could guess, the error message is about Visual Studio. Do you have it installed? (Note, that Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are completely different things).

Comment: Yes i have both installed. But i ran my codes through visual studio code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the latest version of the Visual studio installer even if you have visual studio code installed.
Check the boxes to install desktop development tools for Linux and windows
Check the box to install C++ CMake tools as well
Then proceed with the installation.

Comment: So There's no way to install vcpkg without downloading VS installer?

Comment: well this was the only way i could find after digging all the resources. There might be more ways

Answer (score 1):

you can separately download the package, extract it, then insert it's path to include path in IntelliSense Configurations